# HttpSendRequest not waiting for PHP script to finish

Tags: php, c++, wininet

I'm sending an `HTTP POST request` from my C++ app to a PHP script on a server. Using `HttpOpenRequest/HttpSendRequest/etc`. Currently it waits for the PHP script to finish executing before `HttpSendRequest` returns. Is there anyway to change this functionality?

I'm sending the data just before my C++ application closes, so I don't want it to sit there for 10+ seconds waiting for the PHP script to finish executing. I just want it to send the data, then close the app.

One thing I was thinking was to have the PHP script spawn another PHP script in a different process using the exec command, so the first script would return straight away. However, I'm sending a lot of data with my HTTP POST request, so would need it pass this data to the spawned process.

Ideally I just want a flag to set to tell `HttpSendRequest` not to wait. I couldn't see anything obvious in the docs, but may have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to `ignore_user_abort()` in your PHP script. Then you can close the connection from your C client after the data is sent and PHP will continue to do whatever it's supposed to do.

Comment: The problem is that it's the HttpSendRequest that's blocking. So I can't close the connection until that function returns.

Comment: But it's blocking only until it received the reponse, right? http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#71172

Comment: Aha! The code from the link you posted is what I wanted aswell as the ignore_user_abort() call. The header("Connection: close") plus ob_* functions let me close the connection early. Might be worth updating your post with this info incase anyone else has this problem. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can call `InternetOpen` with the `INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC` and have your callback do nothing of consequence.

Here's some example code to get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/asyncwininet.aspx

Then (as rik suggests), call `ignore_user_abort(true);` at the top of your PHP script to ensure it executes fully.

[ignore_user_abort](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)